# what to do with time complexity of native functions when calculating big-O

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I am learning about time complexity and am noticing that tutorials I have seen do not take into account the time complexity of native functions (Javascript in this example)

The below function that removes duplicate values in an array and return the sorted array would be evaluated with time complexity of O(n) instead of O(n + nlogn). Is O(n) correct? Should we take into account time complexities of native functions when calculating time complexities?

```
function uniqueSort(arr) {
    const store = {};
    const result = [arr[0]];

    for(let i =0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(!store[arr[i]]) {
            result.push(arr[i]);
            store[arr[i]] = true;
        }
    }
    return result.sort((a,b) => a - b);
}
```

Comment: "Big O" doesn't have a universally recognized definition for all languages. To get a precise answer (rather than just use the term descriptively), what counts as a single operation needs to be defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is O(n) correct?

O(N) is not correct. When you evaluate the time complexity of a function you have to account for the time complexity of all operations line by line in the function- including that of native functions. It wouldn't make much sense to call a function O(1) if all you're doing is calling various native functions (that can be quite expensive!) inside of your own function.

The function you provided a snippet of would be O(n + nlog(n)) because there is the operation of looping through the array (O(N)) and the operation of sorting using javascript's native function which is nlog(n).

Oftentimes in Big-O notation we classify a function simply by its slowest operation, so you can also describe the function as being O(nlogn).